# C# int array automatically copying other array

Tags: c#, arrays, sorting

I wrote this code that fills an array and a second array copies the first. I change some numbers in the second array, but when I output both arrays, the first one has also changed.
This is my code:

```
        int[] array1 = new int[5];
        int[] array2 = new int[5];
        int temp;

        for (int i = 0; i < array1.Length; i++)
        {
            array1[i] = i;
        }

        array2 = array1;
        temp = array2[2];
        array2[2] = array2[4];
        array2[4] = temp;

        for (int i = 0; i < array1.Length; i++)
        {
            richTextBox1.Text += array1[i].ToString() + " ";
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < array2.Length; i++)
        {
            richTextBox1.Text += array2[i].ToString() + " ";
        }
```

Can someone explain to me why the output is 0 1 4 3 2 0 1 4 3 2 instead of 0 1 2 3 4 0 1 4 3 2?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because arrays are reference types, assigning `array2 = array1` causes the `array2` variable to reference the same array as `array1`.

**Before assignment:**

```
array1  --->  [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]

array2  --->  [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
```

**After assignment:**

```
array1  --->  [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
         /
array2  -     [0, 0, 0, 0, 0] <-- no longer reachable and will be garbage collected
```

To actually create a copy of an array, call [`Clone`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.array.clone.aspx).

```
array2 = (int[])array1.Clone();
```

**After assignment with Clone:**

```
array1  --->  [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]

array2  -     [0, 0, 0, 0, 0] <-- no longer reachable and will be garbage collected
         \
          ->  [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
```

Notice that the `[0, 0, 0, 0, 0]` array is never actually used, so you don't even need to allocate it.

```
//int[] array2 = new int[5];  <-- delete this line
int[] array2 = (int[])array1.Clone();
```

Answer (score 3):

```
array2 = array1;
```

You now have two variables that refer to the **same** array.

Answer (score 3):

```
array2 = array1;
```

You are not copying the array - `Array` is a reference type and you are assigning another variable to point to **the same array** - there is only one array instance, so if you change its contents through one variable these changes are perceived through the other.

Answer (score 2):

```
array2 = array1;   // here you are losing reference to array2
```

Answer (score 2):

Because Arrays are reference type as others said.

You can use this instead:

```
Array.Copy(array1, array2, array2.Length);
```